# Find n-th derivative of $f(x)=\sqrt{1+\cosh{x}}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

$f(x)=\sqrt{1+\cosh{x}}$

$f'(x)=\frac{\sinh{x}}{2\sqrt{\cosh{x}+1}}$

$f''(x)=\frac{(\cosh{\frac{x}{2}})^4}{(\cosh{x}+1)^\frac{3}{2}}$

I wanted to use Leibnitz rule, but i can't seem to find any similarities between derivatives. I don't know how to expand $\cosh{x}$ as Taylor series. These are the only two general methods i know for finding upper derivatives. I think there must be some trick. Anyone has any ideas?
This is what i got so far. $$f(x)=\frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty ( \frac{(\frac{x}{2})^n}{n!}+\frac{(\frac{-x}{2})^n}{n!})}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2(\frac{x}{2})^{2k}}{(2k)!}}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Dunno what to do now

New approach.

$f(x)=\sqrt{2}\cosh{\frac{x}{2}}$ 
 
$f'(x)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sinh{\frac{x}{2}}$
$f''(x)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\cosh{\frac{x}{2}}=\frac{1}{4}f(x)$

For $n$ even

$f^{(n)}=\frac{1}{2^n}f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2^n}\cosh{\frac{x}{2}}$

For $n$ odd

$f^{(n)}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2^n}\sinh{\frac{x}{2}}$

Comment: $f(x) = \sqrt {2}\cosh \frac {x}{2}$

Comment: Do I? $f(0) = \sqrt 2.$  Pretty sure the \sqrt 2 is in the numerator.

Comment: Doug see the solution, is it ok?

Comment: looks good to me.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an idea: write $${1+\cosh x}=1+\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}=\frac{e^{x}+2+e^{-x}}{2}=\frac{(e^{x/2}+e^{-x/2})^2}{2},$$ so $$f(x)=\sqrt{1+\cosh x}=\frac{e^{x/2}+e^{-x/2}}{\sqrt{2}}.$$ Now use Taylor series.

Comment: Or just have $f(x)=\sqrt2\cos(\frac i2x)$, chain rule on this is much more simple.

Comment: That works too!

Comment: I am first year of math college. We can't use $i$'s. Although, many exercises can be solved using complex analasys

Comment: @RushThaMan Aw, no fun.

Comment: See the edit. Exercise is asking to find $n-th$ derivation, not $n-th$ derivation in zero. That might be problem

Comment: The expression I gave for $f$ is very amenable to taking repeated derivatives - although you wouldn't use Taylor series to do that, my bad.

Comment: Right, no series, just use Chain Rule.

Answer (score 1):

$\cosh x = \frac 12 (e^x+ e^{-x})\\
\cosh^2 x = \frac 14 (e^{2x}+ e^{-2x}+1) = \frac 12 (\cosh 2x + 1)\\
2cosh^2 \frac x2 = \cosh x + 1\\
\sqrt 2 \cosh \frac x2 = \sqrt {\cosh x + 1}\\
f(x) = \sqrt 2 \cosh \frac x2$

Just wanted to verify.

The derivatives:

$f(x) = \sqrt 2 \cosh \frac x2\\
f'(x) = \frac {\sqrt 2}{2} \sinh \frac x2\\
f''(x) = \frac {\sqrt 2}{4} \cosh \frac x2\\
f^{(2k)}(x) =\frac {\sqrt 2}{2^{2k}} \cosh \frac x2\\
f^{(2k+1)}(x) =\frac {\sqrt 2}{2^{2k+1}} \sinh \frac x2$

Comment: Yea, thats it. Turns out, it wasn't that hard.